# Cant Get the value for Databound

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

Im developed the asp.project, im get the sql table data for the my grid view, not a displayed any error, but not showing data in my grid view, how can i fix it/

Thanks,

**Aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<div align="center">

        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Style="font-weight: 700">All Products</asp:Label>

<hr />

    </div>
    <table align="ceneter">

        <tr><td align="cebter">

            <asp:GridView ID="gvAvailableProducts" runat="server"  Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvAvailableProducts_SelectedIndexChanged">





                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Name"  ItemStyle-Width="150">

<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>

                      <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="ProductCategory"  ItemStyle-Width="50">
<ItemStyle Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="AvailableStock" HeaderText="AvailableStock"  ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Larger">

<ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductPrice" HeaderText="Price"  ItemStyle-Width="150">
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>

                     <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductDescription" HeaderText="Description"  ItemStyle-Width="150">
<ItemStyle Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:ImageField DataAlternateTextField="ProductImage" ControlStyle-Width="150">
<ControlStyle Width="150px"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:ImageField>

                </Columns>

                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />


</asp:GridView>


            </td></tr>



    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

---

**SP,**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetAllProdcuts](@CategoryID int)


AS
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
    IF (@CategoryID <> 0) 
    BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM (SELECT 

     P.CategoryID,
     p.ProductID,
     p.ProductName,
     p.ProductPrice,
     p.ProductImage,
     C.CategoryName,
p.ProductDescription,
p.ProductsQuantity,
Isnull (Sum(CP.TotalProducts),0)   AS ProductSold,

     (p.ProductsQuantity -  Isnull (Sum(CP.TotalProducts),0)) AS AvailableStock



     FROM  Products P

      INNER JOIN Category C
     ON C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
      LEFT JOIN CustomerProducts CP
      ON CP.ProductID = P.ProductID


      GROUP BY
     p.ProductID,
     p.ProductName,
     p.ProductPrice,
     p.ProductImage,
      C.CategoryName,
p.ProductDescription,
p.ProductsQuantity,
p.CategoryID) StockTable


WHERE AvailableStock > 0

AND CategoryID = @CategoryID

END 
ELSE



BEGIN 


     SELECT * FROM (SELECT 

     P.CategoryID,
     p.ProductID,
     p.ProductName,
     p.ProductPrice,
     p.ProductImage,
     C.CategoryName,
p.ProductDescription,
p.ProductsQuantity,
ISNULL (SUM(CP.TotalProducts),0)   AS ProductSold,

     (p.ProductsQuantity -  isnull (sum(CP.TotalProducts),0)) AS AvailableStock



     FROM  Products P

      INNER JOIN Category C
     ON C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID
      LEFT JOIN CustomerProducts CP
      ON CP.ProductID = P.ProductID


      GROUP BY
     p.ProductID,
     p.ProductName,
     p.ProductPrice,
     p.ProductImage,
      C.CategoryName,
p.ProductDescription,
p.ProductsQuantity,
p.CategoryID) StockTable


WHERE AvailableStock > 0

AND CategoryID = @CategoryID

END
 END TRY
```

BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT('Error')

CATCH
    END

---

**.cs**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetProducts(0);  //Get All Products   


            }
        }
        private void GetProducts(int CategoryID)
        {


            ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
            {
                CategoryID = CategoryID




            };
            gvAvailableProducts.DataSource = null;
            gvAvailableProducts.DataSource = k.GetAllProducts();

            gvAvailableProducts.DataBind();
```

### }

**Class file**

```
   public DataTable GetAllProducts() {


            SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[1];
            parameters[0] = DataLayer.DataAccess.AddParameter("@CategoryID", CategoryID, System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 20);
            DataTable dt = DataLayer.DataAccess.ExecuteDTByProcedure("SP_GetAllProdcuts", parameters);//Get All Record From SP
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: Debug and check from the page load to data binding everything works as you expect or not

Comment: Sir, im getting a null value, for this `gvAvailableProducts.DataSource = k.GetAllProducts();` what i do it  ? what is the issue for this?

Comment: Im execute the SP and check again  no any error